# Enviar array para PHP através de Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero enviar para o PHP um vetor proveniente do javascript.
Tenho o seguinte codigo mas não está funcionando.Como fazer?

```
    info = [];
    info[0] = 'thiago';
    info[1] = 'carlos';

    alert(info[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {info:info},
        url: "buscar.php",
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Dê um `var_dump($_GET)` no seu arquivo php e um `console.log(msg)` no seu javascript e coloque aqui o retorno;

Comment: esse foi o retorno do console.<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\wamp64\www\ProjetoAJAX2\ex3\buscar.php:13:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  'info' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
      0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'thiago'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
      1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'carlos'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
</pre>

Comment: Foi o retorno no success?

Comment: Tente recuperar essa variável info assim: `$info = json_decode( $_GET['info'] )`

Comment: sim houve retorno .Porém ,quando escrevo um echo na pagina onde os dados deveram está ,não há retorno.

Comment: E como var_dump como o colega sugeriu, o que retorna?

Comment: nao retorna nada !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o seu javascript:

```
 info = [];
    info[0] = 'thiago';
    info[1] = 'carlos';

    alert(info[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {info:info},
        dataType : 'json', 
        url: "buscar.php",
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        }
```

O seu php pode fazer assim para receber o vetor e segue um `foreach` para você testar:

```
<?php
    $teste = $_GET['info'];

    foreach( $teste as $key => $value ){
        echo "{$value}\n";
    }   

?>
```

E se você que retorne no seu `console.log()`

Você pode colar no php simplesmente assim:

```
<?php
    $teste = $_GET['info'];

    echo json_encode( $teste )  ;

?>
```

Espero que possa ajudar

Comment: Uma ultima pergunta.Estou passando 2 vetores desta forma que vc fez no ajax ,só que não há retorno para o console quando escrevo dois echo na pagina do php, um com  echo json_encode(  $_GET['info'] )  ; e outro   json_encode(  $_GET['info2'] )  ; .O que pode ser feito pra que seja retornado os 2 valores

Comment: Não precisa criar dois echo json_encode basta um e colocar os dois dentro, por exemplo: `echo json_encode( array("vetor1" => $vetor1, "vetor2" => $vetor2 ) )` aí no console você mostra assim: `console.log( data.vetor1 )` e/ou `console.log( data.vetor2 )`

Comment: ok.Obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Seu javascript deve estar assim:

```
var info = [];
info[0] = 'thiago';
info[1] = 'carlos';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {info:info},
    url: "buscar.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){
        console.log(msg.info[0]);
    }
});
```

Seu php assim:

```
echo json_encode($_GET);
```

Para pegar os dados no lado do servidor utilize assim:

```
$_GET['info'][0];
```